# Did Agent Smith absorb The Merovingian and/or The Twins?

Tags: the-matrix

Is there a canonical source stating the fate of The Merovingian and/or The Twins (yes yes, there are other henchmen, but that straight razor guys are the coolest) during and after Agent Smith's "New World Order" attempt?

Comment: Speculation: The Merovingian can likely escape to the Train Station. He may be able to create similar constructs. He is described to be able to transfer things from "the machine's world" into "the human's world". He may be able to escape, although it's unknown to what extent this helps him and if Smith can destroy the connection between his hideout and the Matrix or not.

Comment: Weren't the twins killed?? So I'm guessing they weren't!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

During the events that transpire while Smith had possessed the entire population of the Matrix, save for Neo, the Merovingian as well as any of the Exile programs would have been possessed.  However the fate of "Merph" as well as other Exiles, the returned Agents, and those that survived the end of Revolutions is covered in [The Matrix Online](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Matrix_Online).  The story lines from the game have been confirmed as the canonical continuation of the Matrix saga.  As for the [Merovingian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merovingian_%28The_Matrix%29) he survives the reload of the Matrix, and is one of the three factions the player can choose to join in game.  He primarily protected the Exiles, and was not necessarily in the middle of the hostilities between the Machines and Zion.  One of the missions of his faction is to find the fragemts of the RSI codes for the [Twins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twins_%28The_Matrix%29), once they are fully collected, the Twins are restored to full form and return to service to the Merovingian.

[image: the Merovingian]

Comment: 'confirmed as the canonical continuation' - Firstly, do you have a reference for that, and secondly how on earth is anyone meant to be able to reference anything in a game that shut down in 2009. I submit that even if it was once canon it is canon no longer.

Comment: @ClaraOnager The game website, as well as the fact that the Wachowski's had input up through chapter 9 of the game confirm it's canonical.  Your second question makes no sense though, that's like saying "How can a comic series be considered canon if it's discontinued" Just because it's no longer ongoing doesn't mean it didn't count.

Comment: My point is that an online game is not the same as a comic. A comic is a physical object that exists and can be directly referenced first hand (i.e. I can read it). Whereas a game that has gone has no means of viewing the actual content, only third hand sources can be used. Thus it is not anything like as good a source.

Comment: A game is not the same as a comic, no. But if a game is established as canon, then it is canon and can be treated as such. Plenty of primary sources still exist from the game; for example, the screenshot Monty129 provided in his answer is directly from the game and features the Merovingian.

Comment: Not to mention you can just go to youtube and research the cutscenes. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qWPey1fU9Ok

Answer (score 6):

Smith is capable of absorbing other agents so there's no reason why he couldn't also do that to every being in The Matrix.

However the fate of the Merovingian, The Twins, and other of their ilk is not covered in the films. It's likely that they have independent means of entering and exiting The Matrix as some of them are described as being from 'earlier versions' but it is not explicitly stated.

Presumably this is left for the viewer to decide for themselves so any answer here must be speculation.